# Numpy add outer, string change?

Tags: python, arrays, string, numpy, functools

I have a dataframe 
df1=

```
 HPE FRE UNE
0  S0  S0  S0
1  S1  S1  S1
```

using the below code("reduce" is a functool function, sta is a list containing the columns of df1):

```
reduce(lambda x,y:np.add.outer(x,y),sta).reshape(-1)
```

I reduced my dataframe to numpy array like this:

```
['S0S0S0' 'S0S0S1' 'S0S1S0' 'S0S1S1' 'S1S0S0' 'S1S0S1' 'S1S1S0' 'S1S1S1']
```

but I want my output to look like below:

```
['S0|S0|S0' 'S0|S0|S1' 'S0|S1|S0' 'S0|S1|S1' 'S1|S0|S0' 'S1|S0|S1' 'S1|S1|S0' 'S1|S1|S1']
```

How can I do?

Comment: How does this work for you? I get `TypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types`.

Comment: @coldspeed : can you post the code you are trying to execute?

Comment: This kind of `add` only works it the array is object dtype.  Then the array `add` delegates the task to the `add` method of each element, which for strings is a `join`.  It does not work for `string` dtype arrays.  It's a feature, not a designed or documented behavior.

Comment: Can't you treat '|' just like another string that you `add` to the others?

Comment: `reduce(lambda x,y:np.add.outer(x,y),df.T.values.tolist())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do it this way:

```
pd.Series(map('|'.join, itertools.product(*sta)))
```

Assuming a less-degenerate input `df1` to make the example more clear:

```
  HPE FRE UNE
0  AB  CD  EF
1  GH  IJ  KL
```

and `sta = [df1.HPE, df1.FRE, df1.UNE]`, the result is:

```
0    AB|CD|EF
1    AB|CD|KL
2    AB|IJ|EF
3    AB|IJ|KL
4    GH|CD|EF
5    GH|CD|KL
6    GH|IJ|EF
7    GH|IJ|KL
```